# how to aggregate multiple collections in salat mongodb

Tags: mongodb, scala, salat

- I have three collections like WindowsCollection,EsxCollection and
  LinuxCollection in these all three collections documents i have
  cpuUtilization,memoryUtilization,hostID keys. Now i have to find top
  10 records from all three collections and get these key values from
  these top 10 documents and form json like below.  {"cpu":
  [10,20,30,40,550,60,70,80,100,30]   "memory":
  [20,30,40,50,60,30,20,40,50,29]   "hostId":
  [92,30,1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,]  }

  i am working in scala with salat mongodb.any help ..thankx

Comment: MongoDB does not "join" collections in any way. You want separate queries on "each" collection or combine all your data into **one** collection. This is what MongoDB was made for. Not to be used just like a relational database. If you want that functionality then use relational instead.

Comment: actually i have seperate collections but i have to aggregate them ...isn't it possible ?

Comment: It's a very simple statement "no joins". So not possible. Change what you are doing or don't use MongoDB. It's not like that basic information is not readily available.